# How to make profiteroles without a visible hole?

Tags: baking, dessert

I get the choux pastry and how you put filling in it, but there's always a hole left and the filling shows. Does anyone know of a sure-fire way to make a profiterole that looks completely intact from the outside while the filling is in?

Comment: Is 'cover the hole with chocolate ganache' an acceptable answer?

Comment: Also, how large are your holes at present? Covering up a small hole when you've used a syringe is very different to covering a large hole if you cut the pastry open and used a spoon.

Comment: @dbmag9 I'm using a bismarck pastry tip. Syringe is a good idea, I guess. I'll have to work on keeping the custard nice and liquidy for longer.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Like a jelly doughnut or other filled pastry, the bit of filling peeking out from the pastry is appetizing, and also gives a clue that you're looking at a filled pastry, and what it's filled with.

Answer (score 9):

Fill from the bottom. Take a paring knife and cut a half-circle about the size of a dime near one end on the bottom, with the ends of the cut facing the end of the profiterole. This makes a sort of trap-door to get the filler tip into. Afterwards, you can use the paring knife tip to pull the trap door flush with the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Since the filling is inserted after the profiteroles shells are baked, there's no way to not have an opening to, erm,  fill the fillings.

If you are using a piping bag to fill in the profiteroles, try using a smaller attachment.